# How was the busy beaver candidate for 6 states calculated?

Tags: turing-machines

The current busy beaver candidate on 6 states, with the original binary alphabet configuration, produces about 10^18267 1's, according to the wiki page on Busy Beaver. I could not find any working links to research that further. My question is, what methods were applied to emulate such a long running Turing machine? I am also interested in general methods that could produce that kind of a result, even if they were not applied in this case.

Comment: See whether http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~jah/busybeaver/seminarMay05.html gets you anywhere --- it does seem to discuss search strategies for good candidates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heiner Marxen provides a description of several techniques used to simulate extremely long-running Turing machines: http://www.drb.insel.de/~heiner/BB/mabu90.html

First some notation: A TM configuration can be represented like: `10 B> 111101`. Which means that it is in state `B` and the head is over the `1` at position 3 from the left (the symbol that the `>` points to). If this TM has a transition `(B, 1) -> (0, R, B)` then the next configuration will be `100 B> 11101`.

There are specifically 3 techniques:

1. **Tape compression**: Represent a long tape as `1 0 B> 1^18 0 1^2` instead of `10 B> 111111111111111111011`. In addition to potential space savings, this can lead to time savings when you have transitions like `(B, 1) -> (0, R, B)` which can jump over the entire stack of symbols: `1 0 B> 1^18 0 1^2` -> `1 0^19 B> 0 1^2`.
2. **Macro machine**: Instead of considering the TMs actions on each individual symbol, think of it as acting on blocks of N symbols. This allows us to compress the tape like: `11 10 A> 01^6 11`. Many TMs which do not compress well with (1) will with some Macro machine for some block size N.
3. **Proof system**: Finally, by automatically detecting, proving and applying generic rules to specific configurations, you can get significant time improvements for some machines (including all record-holding TMs). An example rule might be: `100^a B> 010^(b+1)` -> `100^(a+2b) B> 010^1` for any `a,b >= 0` in `b^2 - b + 4` steps.